# Calculate the substitution variable length in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have simple plsql program, basically what I would like to do is to calculate the length of the name which is dynamic input to plsql and then loop based on the length.

When I give pre-defined value like v_name = 'Dex' it works but when I give v_name = &name it throws an error message saying Dex must be declared.

Appreciate if any one can shed light on this issue. Please find error and program details below:

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DEX' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

PLsql Program:

```
declare
v_name varchar2(30);
v_loop_count number;
v_len number;
begin
  v_name := &name;
  v_loop_count := 0;
  v_len := length(v_name);
  for v_loop_count in 0 .. v_len-1
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Entered Name is :: '||v_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You still need to put the quotes around the substitution variable or include them in your variable as Oracle is doing a straight substition in your script so the quotes need to wind up there around your string literal.

Comment: I disagree that this is a typographical error.  The OP didn't forget the single-quotes; the OP didn't know that single quotes were required due to the nature of the substitution variables.  I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer (and in sqlplus), you can define substitution variables such as you're doing that start with `&`.  But these substitution variables are unlike variables or literals in your code.  These substitution variables will only be replaced textually, before the code gets parsed and executed.

If you have

```
v_name := &name;
```

Then the textual replacement will yield this code:

```
v_name := Dex;
```

Because you don't have a variable named DEX, you get the error you mentioned.

As mentioned in the comments, placing single-quotes around the substitution variable is the answer.

```
v_name := '&name';
```

This will get replaced with

```
v_name := 'Dex';
```

which is what you wanted -- the string value `'Dex'`.